# CSS Stylesheet edit to remove "Free Entry" on WordPress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Been beating my head against this problem for a bit... It is probably either really easy to do and I am a dolt, or really hard to do and not worth it. Basicly I have a wordpress theme that has a nice Event widget included. It works great but it puts a lame "Free Entry" button on every event. All of our events are free so it's just kind of an eyesoar. I have been trying to edit the stylesheet to remove it but I can't figure it out. Here is the site I am working on: http://comerestministries.com/wordpress/homepage3/

The code I am looking at I think is this:

```
<li class="ecs-event">
  <a href="http://comerestministries.com/wordpress/event/awakening-of-love-2/">
    <p>May/12</p>
    <p>18:30</p>
    <h3>Awakening of Love</h3>
    <span>Free entry</span></a></li>
```

Is there an easy way to remove that final Span tag every time it tries to display... like a "display: none !important;" tag? I tried to add that to the style sheet but couldn't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer is correct. That hides the span. This fixes the aftermath of the space left behind.

```
.ecs-event-list li.ecs-event a > span{
    display: none;
}
.ecs-event-list li.ecs-event a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... now I am having the problem that my child theme (and theme for that matter) stylesheet (edited in the wordpress editor) is not actually changing anything... grrr...

Answer (score 1):

looking at your wp theme, you can like this:

```css
.ecs-event-list li span {
    display: none;
}
```